# How to making sure at least one checkbox is checked using vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I would like to guarantee that at least one checkboxes are checked and the price are correct calculated.

https://jsfiddle.net/snoke/1xrzy57u/1/

```
methods: {
    calc: function (item) {
        item.isChecked = !item.isChecked

        this.total = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            if(this.items[i].isChecked === true) {
                this.total += this.items[i].price;
            }
        }

        // fullPackagePrice
        if(this.items[0].isChecked === true && this.items[1].isChecked === true && this.items[2].isChecked === true) {
            this.total = this.fullPackagePrice;
        }

        // Trying to guarantee that have at least one checkbox checked
        if(this.items[0].isChecked === false && this.items[1].isChecked === false && this.items[2].isChecked === false) {
            this.total = this.items[0].price;
            this.items[0].isChecked = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good fit for this would be using computed properties instead of a method.

Read more about these here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties

A computed property observes all referenced data and when one piece changes, the function is re-run and re-evaluated.

What you could do is first create a `allowCheckout` computed property like this:

```
allowCheckout() {
    return this.items[0].isChecked || this.items[1].isChecked || this.items[2].isChecked;
}
```

You will then use it within the button like this:

`<button :disabled="allowCheckout"...`

This will disable the button when no items are checked.

Next, you'll also want to create a second computed property for the total price

```
totalPrice() {
    // Perform similar checking here to update this.total
}
```

Lastly, you'll want to change your checkboxes to no longer use v-on:change but to instead use v-model for the relevant parameter for each.

This way your checkbox status will be bound to the true/falseness of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to go with your method, you can implement at like shown in [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vhb03ta/18/) and set a variable `atLeastOneItemIsChecked` like this:

```
this.atLeastOneItemIsChecked = this.items.find(item => item.isChecked) !== undefined
```

Do not force the user to always check a checkbox. Instead, display a hint and disable the button using `:disable` and tailwind css resulting in this:

[image: Visualization of the solution]

Comment: Also a good asnwer! :). However, I feel OP should definitely still explore computed properties if he has not yet experienced using them as they are such a powerful VueJS construct